# Unity ClientRpc not called at all

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-mirror

I'm making a Hearthstone like TCG game on Unity 2019.3.3 using mirror for networking.

I made a lobby scene with fake decks to select.
When players are both ready, host can start the game.

So player instances are spawn and the scene changed, when I tried to call a Rpc from `OnServerReady`, on player in order to initialize it, nothing happens on host neither on client.

Player have `NetworkID`

NetworkManager.cs

```
    public override void OnServerReady(NetworkConnection conn)
    {
        base.OnServerReady(conn);
        foreach (var player in RoomPlayers)
        {
            if((!player.IsReady))
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        OnServerReadied?.Invoke(conn);
    }
```

TurnManager.cs

```
    public override void OnStartServer() => NetworkManagerLobby.OnServerReadied += SetUpGame;

    public void SetUpGame( NetworkConnection conn)
    {
        foreach (var player in Room.GamePlayers)
        {
            Debug.Log("Call init rpc on " + player.displayName);
            player.RpcInitializePlayer();
        }
```

Player.cs

```
    [ClientRpc]
    public void RpcInitializePlayer()
    {
        InitializePlayer();
    }

    void InitializePlayer()
    {
        Debug.Log("Initialize " + displayName);

        if (hasAuthority)
        {
            PArea = GameObject.Find("LowerPlayerArea").GetComponent<PlayerArea>();

            ManaForNextTurn = 1;
            CurrentMana = 0;

            deck.DecryptDeck(this);
            CmdSetCharAsset(deck.charAsset);
        }
        else
        {
            PArea = GameObject.Find("TopPlayerArea").GetComponent<PlayerArea>();

            ManaForNextTurn = 1;
            CurrentMana = 0;
        }
    }
```

And the output is

```
Call init rpc on Player1
Call init rpc on Player2
```

insteed of

```
Call init rpc on Player1
Initialize Player1
Call init rpc on player2
Initialize Player2
```

Don't understand what's wrong with my code.

Comment: It suggests player.IsReady is false then or they aren’t in the room.

Comment: @BugFinder if they were not in the room then the event would be invoked anyway and there would be no iterations later. OP states though that the first log `Call init rpc on PlayerXY` **is** being logged meaning the line `player.RpcInitializePlayer();` seems to be definitely reached so the event itself and `Room.GamePlayers` seems to be not the issue :)

Comment: Yes, as @derHugo mentioned, players are in the room, they are spawned, `OnStartClient` and `OnStartAuthority` is called on each.